# How to Add a Cool Down Between Collision Events in Python?

Tags: python, time, collision-detection

We are currently creating a game with python at my school. The game I'm making involves dodging enemies, but there is a problem: multiple collision events get activated at once, taking away all the players health. I found the temporary solution of teleporting the player but, if an enemy is at the new location, they get stuck there and die. I tried adding a few invincibility frames but it's behaving strangely.

```py
def collision(player, hit_sprite):
    global score
    global score_text
    global lives
    play = player.get_image_name()
    if play == "player_sprite_049":
        hit = hit_sprite.get_image_name()
        if hit == "green_star_96c":
            stage.remove_sprite(score_text)
            stage.remove_sprite(hit_sprite)
            score += 1
            score_text = codesters.Text(str(score), 200, 200, "white")
            return score_text
        if hit == "enemy_bullet_62c" or hit == "the_floater_1ee" or hit == "the_chaser_4a0":
            lives -= 1
            player.load_image("player_sprite_invincible_867")
            stage.wait(2)
        if lives <= 0:
            stage.remove_sprite(player)
            GAME = codesters.Text("GAME OVER", 0, 0, "red")
        if lives <= 3:
            stage.remove_sprite(H3)
        if lives <= 2:
            stage.remove_sprite(H2)
        if lives <= 1:
            stage.remove_sprite(H1)
        player.load_image("player_sprite_049")
    else:
        sound = codesters.Sound("drum_bell")
        sound.play()
player.event_collision(collision)
```

Comment: Can you post some of the collision checking code?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to the player, that stores the object which had hit the player:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
   
        self.was_hit_by = None
```

Discard the collision in the function `collision` if the player collides several times in a row with the same object:

```py
def collision(player, hit_sprite):
    
    if player.was_hit_by == hit_sprite:
        reteurn:
    player.was_hit_by = hit_sprite

    # [...]
```

Reset the `was_hit_by` attribute if the player does not collide with any object:

```py
if collide:
    collision(player, hit_sprite)
else
    player.was_hit_by = None
```